# How do I get to a Stack Overflow profile from a Stack Overflow CV?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Is there a link I'm missing somehow from a user's CV back to their Stack Overflow questions and answers, or is that information intentionally omitted?

I am interested to read the posts from Antoine Pritou, who's an active [CPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) core developer and has contributed many great patches to the Python language.

Comment: You cannot easily unless the user has placed his profile on the cv.  Aside from that the CV sections can also be made private so even if he did have answers or questions there is a possibility he is hiding them.

Comment: The last seen on stack overflow date might also be helpful in locating

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no reason to hunt for people via the information that is readily available.  Some people prefer their profiles not be linked to directly.

Comment: I don't see how that makes this question off-topic, exactly.  Why not post your comments as an answer instead?